# C# deserialize XML to a custom class

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I have one single configuration XML file which can be deserialised into different instances, each of which takes only a portion of this XML.

```
class A
{
    public string A { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public string B { get; set; }
}

public static T Xml2Cls<T>(string filename)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
    var root = new XMLRootAttribte(doc.Root.Name.LocalName);
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer(typeof(T), root);
    using (var reader = doc.Root.CreateReader())
    {
        return (T)serializer .Deserialize(reader);
    }
}

// if I keep calling the following for say 1000 times
// all these instances don't seem to get garbage collected
var a = Xml2Cls<A>("a.xml");
var b = Xml2Cls<B>("a.xml");

<root>
    <a>...</a>
    <b>...</b>
</root>
```

Any ideas why those instantiated objects are not garbage collocted? I tried moving the `return` out of the `using` block but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: So what is the *actual* question? It should be clearly summarized in the title and expanded/clarified outside of the code block.

Comment: Are you getting some sort of error? You didn't make it clear what the issue is. "Any ideas" is not much use as a question if you don't explain the problem.

Comment: Where do you get the idea something isn't garbage collected? You aren't looking at the Memory column in Task Manager are you? That [doesn't show memory in active use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4863113/22437).

Comment: @DourHighArch the memory monitoring in visual studio

Comment: Why do you believe `var a = …` somehow should be instantly garbage collected? Or you are asking about some other objects ? (Very unclear at this point what exactly is the problem)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov those code are in a function in the real code. So as soon as that function returns, they should be destroyed. Or if there is a delay for GC, they should be collected 1 minute or so later. But the VS memory profiling shows that the memory keeps increasing even after 1 minute.

Comment: "So as soon as that function returns, they should be destroyed."???? Can you show [mcve] that explains why you expect that behavior of GC? Where "collected 1 minute or so later" comes from? (I don't think there any configuration you can set to make GC to behave that way - so clearly you have code that force GC - make sure to include that in sample) - again showing good self-contained example would be really helpful.

Comment: As far as I know garbage collection are more dependant on memory usage than elapsed time.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry I can't put all the code up here because the whole thing is just too big. I don't have any code to force GC. To put it another way, if I keep it running for 1 hour, the memory usage will always be increasing with all code commented out but only the `Xml2Cls`.

Comment: @Phil1970 The whole thing finally got an `Out of Memory` exception.

Comment: Then either you keep reference to all loaded documents or those are very large files (say hundreds of megabytes). To get an `Out of memory` you really need to have a lot of big objects.

Comment: @Antediluvian https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+xmlserializer+outofmemory - should be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805738/net-outofmemoryexception-on-xmlserializer-serialize (but I already used up my vote)

Comment: @Phil1970 no... just call XmlSerialization enough times. I was completely confused about the way OP phrased the question and it looked like a,b… are not getting collected (which makes no sense) or they have strange expectation of GC...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That helped. I didn't know that it was the problem of the serialiser. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't provide real code. If you have 1000 variables a, b,... and each string is a 1MB file, then it it possible to get out-of-memory because you have 1GB of memory just for that (a 32 bit application would have 2GB available for user in theory. It could be a bit less in practice)

Comment: @Phil1970 The XML itself is only 4K. For a 1M string or whatever, I would rather use streams instead.